# Unable to allocate memory on an embedded device

Tags: c, pointers, memory, stm32, keil

I know that it is discouraged to use malloc in an embedded environment, but I found example relevant to what I need that used it and it worked fine for me.

This is the code, whose execution I find slightly perplexing:

```
    uint8_t * buffer;  // pointer to buffer                           
    uint8_t * buffer1; // pointer to buffer1 
    uint8_t * buffer2; // pointer to buffer2 

    buffer  = malloc(400 * sizeof(uint8_t));    // size of buffer
    buffer1 = malloc(400 * sizeof(uint8_t));    // size of buffer1
    buffer2 = malloc(400 * sizeof(uint8_t));    // size of buffer2
```

These are the watchwindows for the values of the pointers, at the beginning of the debug execution.

[image]

After an execution to a breakpoint located after the end of the above code snippet.

[image]

When stepping through using debugger, after the `malloc` lines I can see that the first line will allocate address for the `buffer` pointer. It will only do so to the `buffer` though and not to either `buffer1` or `buffer2`.

This is true when changing the order of memory allocation as in the code below:

```
    uint8_t * buffer;  // pointer to buffer                           
    uint8_t * buffer1; // pointer to buffer1 
    uint8_t * buffer2; // pointer to buffer2 

    buffer1 = malloc(400 * sizeof(uint8_t));    // size of buffer
    buffer  = malloc(400 * sizeof(uint8_t));    // size of buffer1
    buffer2 = malloc(400 * sizeof(uint8_t));    // size of buffer2
```

In this instance pointer `buffer1` will have non-zero value while others will be null, as displayed in the watch below.

[image]

Testing code like the one below, will cause it to assign a value to the pointer `buffer1` and when allocating memory to it again it will set it again to zero.

```
    uint8_t * buffer;  // pointer to buffer
    uint8_t * buffer1; // pointer to buffer1 
    uint8_t * buffer2; // pointer to buffer2 

    buffer1 = malloc(400 * sizeof(uint8_t));    // size of buffer1
    buffer  = malloc(400 * sizeof(uint8_t));    // size of buffer
    buffer1 = malloc(400 * sizeof(uint8_t));    // size of buffer1
```

Code crashes later down the line when assert() is performed on an empty pointer value when a struct with one of the buffers is initialised.

I am using malloc to begin with only because of this [code for implementing circular buffer](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/4/6/circular-buffers-in-cc) that I found online.

While I'm not new to the pointers/memory related stuff it does take me by suprise more often than not. I am guessing that I am fundamntally misunderstanding how memory gets (or not) allocated or in how debugger and watch windows update pointer values.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Some embedded systems don't have any working `malloc`. And `malloc` is permitted to fail, then returning `NULL`

Comment: malloc is returning a null pointer when there is an error. Are you sure you have enough memory there? How is malloc specified for your device?

Comment: I doubt you have a proper `malloc` implementation and/or space allocated for heap on your environment.

Comment: @Govind Parmar  that sounds like something to do using the SWD, which I don't think I have access to with the board the MCU is on.

Comment: You made sure that all optimization is disabled while debugging this?

Comment: @PJRobot Yeah all optimasation is off.

Comment: I guess you also checked the heap size in target dialogue (or startup assembly)?

Comment: @GovindParmar It is worth noting that while the Unix 98 standard requires `malloc` to set `errno` upon failure, the C standard itself does not, so it is quite possible that the message from `perror` would be unrelated to the call to `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a provided project template in Keil ARM-MDK, the allocated heap size is normally rather small.  You need to set its size appropriately for your application.

Your project will include start-up assembler code called startup_stm32xxxxx.s (where xxxxx is part specific).  This file contains mark-up comments that are recognised by the uVision editor so that when you open the file, the editor windows will have two tabs at the bottom - one for the source and one for the configuration.  You can modify the stack and heap sizes through either.

Example below (for a different part than yours, so the parameters may differ but at least stack and heap will be present):
[image]